# Show a piecewise-defined function is one-to-one

Tags: real-analysis, functions, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose we can express any positive raional number $x$ uniquely as $x = \frac{p}{q}$, where $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define the mapping $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$ by the following:

$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if}\, x=0;\\
2((p+q)^{2} + q) &\text{if}\,x=\frac{p}{q}>0, \gcd(p,q)=1;\\
1+g(-x) &\text{if}\,x<0.
\end{cases}
$

I am trying to show that this mapping is injective.

This is what I've done so far:

> $g(0) = 1$ by definition, $\displaystyle g\left( \frac{q}{p}\right) \neq 1$ $\forall p, q$, clearly, and $g(x) = 1+g(-x) = 1$ only when $g(-x)=0$, which it cannot be since $g: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$, and $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. So, only $x = 0 \mapsto 1$.

Now, I am trying to show that if $\displaystyle g\left(\frac{p}{q} \right) = g\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)$ for $m, n \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\gcd(m,n)=1$ as well, then we must have $\displaystyle \frac{p}{q} = \frac{m}{n}$.

So, I set $(p+q)^{2} + q = (m+n)^{2}+n$, and am now trying to derive $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{m}{n}$, but I am not having much luck.

What do I need to do to get what I want to pop out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $g$ is injective reduces to checking that the function $f(m,n)=(m+n)^2 +n$ defined on positive integers $m,n$ is injective.

Observe that $$(m+n)^2< f(m,n)<f(m,n)+n+2m+1=(m+n+1)^2.$$
Therefore $m+n=\lfloor\sqrt{f(m,n)}\rfloor$. Thus $$n=f(m,n)-\lfloor\sqrt{f(m,n)}\rfloor^2,\quad m=\lfloor\sqrt{f(m,n)}\rfloor-n$$
determines both $m$ and $n$ uniquely from $f(m,n)$.

Comment: Of course, if you start with things that are equal the function is uniquely defined. Is saying what you just said equivalent to saying that $f(x)  = f(y)$ implies that $x = y$?

Comment: I think it would be better to suppose $\displaystyle \frac{p}{q} \neq \frac{m}{n}$.  Then, would $\gcd(p,q)=\gcd(m,n)=1$ also imply necessarily that $p \neq \pm m$ and $q \neq \pm n$?

Comment: I misread your question! Fixing my answer... (sorry)

Comment: What does that symbol that looks like an L mean? Floor function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: I think you also meant $f(m,n) + 2n + 2m + 1  = (m+n+1)^{2}$.

Comment: No, because $f(n,m)$ already has an extra $n$ term. Think about it.

Comment: Yes, you're right! My bad.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Comment: I wish I could find a proof that $\lfloor x \rfloor = m$ iff $m \leq x < m + 1$.

Comment: @JessyCat... Isn't that the definition, when $m$ is an integer?

Comment: @Clarinetist, I would think so, but some places I'm looking are telling me that it's something to be proved.

Comment: @JessyCat How would you define the floor of $x$ otherwise?

Comment: Yes, you're right.